# Keeping Sub-headers as TRUE in R while reading files

Tags: r

I am using R 3.2.3, I want to know if there is any way to keep your Sub-headers as TRUE, like we have `headers=TRUE` while reading a file with headers.

For example, let's say data looks like below in a file

```
    Quality         <-- Header
Bad       Good      <-- Sub-header
2          4
3          7
1          11
```

So, I need to keep the header and sub-headers as TRUE in R while reading the file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is such thing. Your best bet is to use  `Quality_Bad`, `Quality_Good` as header

Comment: It's not clear to me how you would want your data to look exactly.

Comment: @Ananta Well yes, that is one way for sure, but was thinking if R has any commands for these.

Comment: @Dason I just want R not to read by headers and sub-headers as a row. So for headers we have headers=TRUE in read.table() or read.csv(), but I do not find an option for sub-headers.